# Is there an equivalent to the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy for mathematics?

Tags: education, philosophy

If not: where do you go when you want a short, accessible overview of an area of research?

Comment: Perhaps Wikipedia?

Comment: Equivalent?${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Are you asking, "Is there an $\textit{Encylopedia of Mathematics}$?  The answer is yes.

Comment: The Encyclopedia of Mathematics is similarly scholarly and useful: https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Main_Page See also the Princeton Companion: https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691118802/the-princeton-companion-to-mathematics

Comment: It sounds like [The Princeton Companion to Mathematics](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691118802/the-princeton-companion-to-mathematics) and [The Princeton Companion to Applied Mathematics](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691150390/the-princeton-companion-to-applied-mathematics) are what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like [The Princeton Companion to Mathematics](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691118802/the-princeton-companion-to-mathematics) and [The Princeton Companion to Applied Mathematics](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691150390/the-princeton-companion-to-applied-mathematics) are what you need.

**The Princeton Companion to Mathematics**

- The must-have compendium on pure mathematics
- This is a one-of-a-kind reference for anyone with a serious interest in mathematics. Edited by Timothy Gowers, a recipient of the Fields Medal, it presents nearly two hundred entries, written especially for this book by some of the world’s leading mathematicians, that introduce basic mathematical tools and vocabulary; trace the development of modern mathematics; explain essential terms and concepts; examine core ideas in major areas of mathematics; describe the achievements of scores of famous mathematicians; explore the impact of mathematics on other disciplines such as biology, finance, and music — and much, much more.

**The Princeton Companion to Applied Mathematics**

- The must-have compendium on applied mathematics
- This is the most authoritative and accessible single-volume reference book on applied mathematics. Featuring numerous entries by leading experts and organized thematically, it introduces readers to applied mathematics and its uses; explains key concepts; describes important equations, laws, and functions; looks at exciting areas of research; covers modeling and simulation; explores areas of application; and more.